# JS content not showing

Tags: javascript, tabs, show

I have few tabs made with jquery function tabs();

```
<div class="vtabs">
  <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
  <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a>
</div>

<div id="tab1" class="vtabs-content">
  Any html content
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="vtabs-content" style="display:none">
  <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div>
</div>


  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
  $('.vtabs a').tabs();
  //--></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init);

        function init () {
            ymaps.geocode('', { results: 1 }).then(function (res) {
                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                window.myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                    zoom: 17
                });
            .
            .
            .
    </script>
```

So the first tab is shown when I click second tab the js content in div with id - map not showing. Though if I press firebug this div everything appears!

How to make this content show?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - don't use same id's for different divs ('tab1')

Comment: Oh it is just mistake here. Sure it is different. I made code simpler for you)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unique id's and place everything inside a div

```
<div id="vtabs">
 <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
 <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a>


 <div id="tab1" class="vtabs-content">
    Any html content
 </div>

<div id="tab2" class="vtabs-content" >
  <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div>
 </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#vtabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Oh it is just mistake here. Sure it is different. I made code simpler for you) Any more suggestions?

Comment: well, I can't give any suggestions when the code you are posting is not the code you are using. Remember, we are talking computers here. 1=1 and 1<>1.0000000000001